# Input of type text not re-rendering on state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a piece of code:
App.js

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import Input from './Components/Input';
export default function App() {
  const [state,setState]=useState(0);
  const handler=()=>{
    setState(prev=>prev+1);
  }
  return <>

  <Input></Input>
  <button onClick={handler}>Change state</button>
  <p>{state}</p>
  </>  

}
```

and Input.js:

```
export default function Input()
{
    return <input type="text"></input>
}
```

The problem is that on changing the state by clicking on the button the Input is not re-rendering while it should as the parent is re-rendering and I know for a fact that children re-render even if their props don't change when parent re-renders. It keeps the value that I type in the input and does not re-render. Same is the case when I use `<input type="text">` or `<Input prop="dummyProp"></Input>` instead of `<Input></Input>`.I am not using strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the state as a param to the component

```
import React , { useState} from 'react';

function Input({ state })
{
    return <input type="text" value={state}></input>
}

export function App(props) {
   const [state,setState]=useState(0);
  const handler=()=>{
    setState(prev=>prev+1);
  }
  return <>

  <Input state={state}></Input>
  <button onClick={handler}>Change state</button>
  <p>{state}</p>
  </>  
}
```

Comment: I know for a fact that children re-render even if their props don't change when parent re-renders...In the above situation, the question asks why the Input is not re-rendering and keeping the value that it is given.

Comment: You don't send any value to the input in your example. What value is the input keeping?

Comment: the value I type in it